# How is sajday sahaw offered?

Tags: salat

Please tell me how is sajday sahaw offered and what if a person forgets to do sajday sahaw? Do we have to re-offer that salat?
Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

**Sajda** means the act of prostrating and **Sahu** means being inattentive or forgetful.

The Prophet has taught us that this is done if we make a mistake in any of the actions of prayer, and when we completed the prayer, we are suppose to do two prostrations.

Now here's the easiest way to remember on when to do them =

- If you added something to the prayer, you should do the prostration AFTER the salaam
- If you left something out of the prayer, you should do the prostrations BEFORE the salaam

This is taken from the actions of Rasolullah, since he didn't explicitly tell us when to do them.

Now, if you have forgotten to do the Sajda Sahu, you can do them at anytime when you remember.  Because the Prophet didn't tell us that Sajda Sahu is done while praying but he said to do Sajda Sahu if we forgot how many ra'kat we did.  The wording is general.

So lets say you finished the prayer and a few hours later, you remembered you forgot to do Sajda Sahu.  You should go into sitting position and do two prostrations.

Allaho Alim.